# how to add images in scrollview from another viewController button clicked in ios

Tags: ios

Two Classes :
1) DemoPage.h & DemoPage.m And 
2) View1.h & View1.m

DemoPage class has scrollview, `view1` has 16 buttons, when `view1`'s `button1` clicked the `image1` wants to add in scrollview of DemoPage class.

I used below code but not working:

```
DemoPage *demoPage = [DemoPage alloc]init];
demoPage.imgViewForRelax.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bird2.png"];
[demoPage.scrollViewForRelax addSubview:demoPage.imgViewForRelax];
```

Comment: What is the type of `DemoPage` ?

Comment: you need to describe Your Demo Page is View ViewController or What ?

Comment: first you should create the small DB seperate in view1 and change the images on scroll view w.r.t that DB on Demopage

Comment: DemoPage is ViewController And View1 is also ViewController

Answer (score -1):

You should read about MVC design pattern. For this you need model which will store images from view1 and display it in Demo.

Comment: can You give Explanation with source Code ?